# Stored procedure and bad data type nvarchar to numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a problem with my stored procedure in SQL Server 2012.

First the table  :

```
    [ProductId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](500) NOT NULL,
    [Category] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Price] [decimal](16, 2) NOT NULL,
```

and the stored procedure :

```
    CREATE procedure [dbo].[GetProductsPaging]
    (@PageOffset bigint=0, 
     @PageSize bigint=5,  
     @OrderBy varchar(30) = 'ProductId',  
     @DescOrder bit = 0) 
    AS
BEGIN
    IF @DescOrder = 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM [dbo].Products
        ORDER BY
            CASE @OrderBy
                WHEN 'ProductId' THEN ProductId
                WHEN 'Name' THEN Name
                WHEN 'Category' THEN Category
                WHEN 'Price' THEN Price
                ELSE NULL
            END ASC
        OFFSET @PageOffset ROWS
        FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY
    END
    ELSE 
    BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM [dbo].Products
        ORDER BY
            CASE @OrderBy
                WHEN 'ProductId' THEN ProductId
                WHEN 'Name' THEN Name
                WHEN 'Category' THEN Category
                WHEN 'Price' THEN Price
                ELSE NULL
            END DESC
        OFFSET @PageOffset ROWS
        FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY
    END
END
```

When I execute it like this

```
EXEC dbo.GetProductsPaging 0, 0 ,'Price', 0
```

the procedure works just fine, but when using this

```
EXEC dbo.GetProcedurePaging 0, 0, 'Name', 0
```

I get this error

> Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.

Someone can help me with this ? Thank for any answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All output options from a case must be of the same datatype,  I think the case decides what output type to use from the first option, and attempts to cast the other values to that type,  In your case, the first and last options, (ProductId and Price), are numeric, buit the others are character... modify the case (in both places) as follows:

```
CASE @OrderBy
  WHEN 'ProductId' THEN str(ProductId, 7, 0) 
  WHEN 'Name' THEN Name
  WHEN 'Category' THEN Category
  WHEN 'Price' THEN str(Price, 16,4)
  ELSE NULL
END ASC
```

realize however that any sorting on the price will now be done on character basis, i.e., 100 will come before 20

Comment: I test sorting on the price and it still sort right, 100 come after 20

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because of your `CASE` expression. First line of your case is `WHEN 'ProductId' THEN ProductId` and therefore it is converting every other field to the same datatype as `ProductId`. It *works for* `Price` as Price can be converted as INT but *fails for* `Name` *as* `it encounters an error converting data type nvarchar to numeric`.

Try this to get the same results:

```
CASE @OrderBy
        WHEN 'ProductId' THEN RIGHT(100000000 + ProductId, 8)
        WHEN 'Name' THEN Name
        WHEN 'Category' THEN Category
        WHEN 'Price' THEN RIGHT(100000000 + Price, 8)
        ELSE NULL
     END ASC
```

`Right()` function is used to get the same order for numeric and varchar values of your ProductId and Price columns. Please apply the same changes for `Order by DESC` section.

Answer (score 1):

```
ORDER BY
        CASE @OrderBy
            WHEN 'ProductId' THEN ProductId
            WHEN 'Name' THEN Name
            WHEN 'Category' THEN Category
            WHEN 'Price' THEN Price
            ELSE NULL
        END ASC
```

won't work when you are mixing numeric and non numeric branches. The type of the `CASE` expression is that of the branch with the highest datatype precedence. You can use

```
ORDER BY
        CASE @OrderBy
            WHEN 'ProductId' THEN ProductId
            WHEN 'Name' THEN Name
            WHEN 'Category' THEN Category
            WHEN 'Price' THEN Price
            ELSE CAST(NULL AS SQL_VARIANT)
        END ASC
```

or

```
ORDER  BY CASE
            WHEN 'ProductId' = @OrderBy THEN ProductId
          END,
          CASE
            WHEN 'Name' = @OrderBy THEN Name
          END,
          CASE
            WHEN 'Category' = @OrderBy THEN Category
          END,
          CASE
            WHEN 'Price' = @OrderBy THEN Price
          END
```

Also you might get a better plan if you use `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` with this last one.